# How inheritance and Prototype Chain works in JS

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

Have a look on my code. I don't understand how It's working

```js
function doSomething() {
  this.testProp = 'testProp';
}

doSomething.testProp1 = "testProp1";
var doSomeInstancing = new doSomething();

console.log("doSomething.testProp:" + doSomething.testProp);
//undefined
console.log("doSomething.testProp1:" + doSomething.testProp1);
//testProp1
console.log(doSomething.hasOwnProperty('testProp1'));
//true 

console.log("doSomeInstancing.testProp:" + doSomeInstancing.testProp);
//testProp
console.log("doSomeInstancing.testProp1:" + doSomeInstancing.testProp1);
//undefined   
console.log(doSomeInstancing.hasOwnProperty('testProp1'));
//false
```

The question is why testProp is undefined in doSomething and not in doSomeInstancing and vice versa for testProp1.

Comment: `doSomething` is the name of your function object. The value of `this` in the constructor when you call it with `new` is **not** a reference to the function object, but a reference to a newly-created object.

Comment: yes it is reference to a newly-created object but I don't get it why it remain undefined in doSomething and vice versa for testProp1

Comment: You do not show anything using inheritance or the prototype chain. Both `testProp` and `testProp1` are assigned to an object. Either to the function or to the object that is an instance of that function, but not to the `prototype`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with inheritance or prototypes

Comment: @Liam yes but I want to extend it later to inhertance

Comment: @t.niese can you post it as answer with some more detail

Comment: Your title and your questions have a distinct disconnect. If you don't want to know about inheritence or prototypes ("I want to extend it later to inhertance") then why the title?

Comment: @Liam actually I came across with it while I was trying to understand Prototype chain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dealing with two distinct objects here:

the function: `doSomething`
the object:   `doSomeInstancing`

Both are objects and both can have properties. `doSomeInstancing` is the object returned from the function when you call `new doSomething()` and it is what `this` refers to in the body of the function. Adding properties to this object has no effect on the other object, the `doSomething` function. The opposite is also true.

If you are trying to inherit a property, you are actually looking for a third object: `doSomething.prototype`. This is a property of functions that points to an object that instances will be linked to. `doSomeInstancing` will inherit from this object to in the prototype chain. For example:

```js
function doSomething() {
  this.testProp = 'testProp';
}

doSomething.prototype.testProp1 = "testProp1 value"

let p = new doSomething()

// p's parent in the protoype chain is doSomething.prototype
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(p) === doSomething.prototype)

console.log(p.testProp)
console.log(p.testProp1)
```